# Pyspark grouped by index and combine list columns into one column of list of lists

Tags: python, pyspark

For a given pyspark dataframe, what is the best way to aggregate columns were contents are lists and create a new column where the contents are list of lists?

example input:

```
id_1|id_2|id_3|        timestamp     |thing1       |thing2       |thing3
A   |b  |  c |[time_0,time_1,time_2]|[1.2,1.1,2.2]|[1.3,1.5,2.6]|[2.5,3.4,2.9]
A   |b  |  d |[time_0,time_1]       |[5.1,6.1]    |[5.5,6.2]   |[5.7,6.3]
A   |b  |  e |[time_0,time_1]       |[0.1,0.2]    |[0.5,0.3]   |[0.9,0.6]
```

example output:

```
id_1|id_2|id_3|        timestamp     |agg_things       
A   |b  |  c |[time_0,time_1,time_2]|[[1.2,1.1,2.2],[1.3,1.5,2.6],[2.5,3.4,2.9]]
A   |b  |  d |[time_0,time_1]       |[[5.1,6.1],[5.5,6.2],[5.7,6.3]]
A   |b  |  e |[time_0,time_1]       |[[0.1,0.2],[0.5,0.3],[0.9,0.6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple code for this:

```
example_df.withColumn('agg_things', array(col("thing1"), col("thing2"), col("thing3")))
```